# What is the correct way of matching a span by text it is wrapping in an element query?

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is something like following possible?

```
const span= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span:containts("some text")'));
```

or is there something like a `.cssContainingText` like with protractor? As a css selector or some other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: my question is not limited to css selectors.

Comment: Its possible with Jquery using :contain , I'm not sure about Angular

Comment: I am asking angular please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach:

```ts
const spans = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('span'));
const span = spans.find(span => span.nativeElement.textContent.includes('some text'))
```